# How to count lines using regex?

Tags: regex, count

Is there any way to use regex equation to get number of lines in a CSV file or any text file .
If please can any one help me with this and if possible explain in 
https://regex101.com website so that I can transform according to my requirement

My data

```
Ahsh,h,1828,8
Euheh,r,1738,7
Hshs,6,7662,7
```

Regex equation:- I need to get here regex equation

Replace Val:- here I need a substitute value which has count like (3)

Much thanks

Comment: Why must you use a RegEx? Why is a simple command like [`wc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wc_(Unix)) unacceptable?

Comment: @DourHighArch actually we are using a tool to get data from a source and transform into valid CSV file but we need to get the count and store in a table as a column so for this regex is very convenient as per our requirement